# Can I use getters/setters for a variable in a closure using the revealing module pattern?

Tags: javascript, revealing-module-pattern

I thought that I could use a setter to change a closure variable, but when I access the variable directly it's unchanged. Only when I access it using a getter do I get the expected reassigned variable. Is there a second variable being created in some different scope? What is happening here?

```
var obj = (function () {
  var name = "one";
  var setName = function(strName) {
    name = strName;
  };
  var getName = function() {
    return name;
  };

  return {
    name: name,
    setName: setName,
    getName: getName
  };
}());

obj.setName("two");

alert("obj.name is: " + obj.name); // Prints "one", but why not "two"?
alert("obj.getName() is: " + obj.getName()); // Prints "two" as I'd expect.
```

I've added the example above to a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8CsZ2/)

Comment: Please include enclosing brackets in your IIFEs so that it's obvious that it's an IIFE **before** I get to the last line of code!! (i.e. `var obj = (function () {…}());`

Comment: Fixed just for you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code:

```
var obj = function () {
  var name = "one";
```

This *name* is a property of the local variable object. This is the one that *setName* and *getName* have a reference to. It is resolved on the scope chain.

```
  return {
    name: name,
```

This *name* is a property of the returned object, i.e. it's a different "name" and is resolved using object property identify resolution (i.e. which is completely different to resolving identifiers on the scope chain). The line above assigns the current value of the local variable name, there is no closure here.

*setName* and *getName* are setting the closed variable, *obj.name* is not modified by those functions.

Answer (score 5):

You could use [Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) to accomplish what you're trying to do:

```js
var obj = function () {
    var name = "one";
    var setName = function(strName) {
        name = strName;
    };
    var getName = function() {
        return name;
    };

    var result = {
        setName: setName,
        getName: getName
    };

    Object.defineProperty(result, 'name', { get: getName });

    return result;
}();

obj.setName("two");

alert("obj.name is: " + obj.name); // two
alert("obj.getName() is: " + obj.getName()); // two
```

Here's the updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/potatosalad/8CsZ2/1/

Answer (score 2):

```
return {
    name: name,
    setName: setName,
    getName: getName
  };
```

The above object is being created before you update the variable, so it will have the old value

Comment: So if I understand correctly, I return an object with a copy of the local name variable, not a reference to it.

Answer (score 1):

The logic you may be looking for is:

```
var obj = function () {
    var name = "one";
    var setName = function(strName) {
        this.name = strName;
    };
    var getName = function() {
        return this.name;
    };

    return {
        name: name,
        setName: setName,
        getName: getName
    };
}();

obj.setName("two");

alert("obj.name is: " + obj.name); // one
alert("obj.getName() is: " + obj.getName()); // two
```

What `this` (in `this.name`) represents may be misleading.

When the method `obj.setName()` is called, the `this.name` represents the name property in the returned object, not the first `name` variable at the top.

`this` keyword info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3127440/1538708

Answer (score 0):

In this case you are storing reference to closure properties in the object.

When you override the values of the closure variables, the object properties still will have reference to the old objects.